# How to apply HDR fillter to image in flutter

Tags: java, android, flutter, colorfilter, hdrimages

I am trying to add **HDR** filter effect to image in flutter using `photofilters: ^3.0.1` library. In this library **HDR** filter is not available so I try to make custom.

What I try

```
class HDRISHFilter extends ColorFilter {
  HDRISHFilter() : super(name: "HDR-ish") {
    subFilters.add(new SaturationSubFilter(0.5));
    subFilters.add(new HueRotationSubFilter(30));
  }
}
```

Expected output is HDR-ish:

[image]

Comment: HDR is not so much an effect, as much as it is an **editing tool**. It actually takes several images and composes them together into one, taking the brightest and darkest parts from each, to give you a wider range of details in the photo.

Comment: Okay I got it but is there any way to do this effect on images? I download some app from app store and check HDR effects on images.  @triple7

Comment: Flutter as full image manipulation capabilities, so if you know what you're doing, you could very much create this effect on your own. You might be able to see what people do for "Fake HDR effects" in other tools (like Photoshop) and then translate those same steps (duplicating the image, changing exposure, merging, etc.) into your code as a custom `applyHdrEffect` method .

Comment: Still I need some proper example how this work and how we can implement HDR-ish effect.